# Cannot read property "setState" of null with React Native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My data is coming from the Firebase nested table and when I set the state it gives me an error that cannot read property setState of null.
This is my code:

```js
componentWillMount(){
  var refx = firebase.database().ref("tutorCopy")
  refx.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      childSnapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
        console.log(childSnap.val());
        this.setState({ markers: Object.values(childSnap.val()) })
      });
    });
  });
}
```

In the constructor I am initializing markers as an array:

```js
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    markers: [],
  }
}
```

And that is my FlatList:

```js
<FlatList
  data={this.state.markers}
  renderItem={
    ({ item }) =>
      <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#000' }}>{item.useremail}</Text>
      </View>
  }
  style={{ width: '100%' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so,

1st - You should not set the sate inside a loop because you're overriding the current state

2nd - Try this instead:

```js
componentDidMount(){

  let markers = []
  var refx = firebase.database().ref("tutorCopy")
  refx.once("value", snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {

      childSnapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
        markers.push(childSnap.val())
        console.log(childSnap.val());

      });
    })
  });
  this.setState({
    markers: markers
  })
}
```

Comment: Actually I can view data in console but now I dont get any error just marker is not setting values stored in childSnap.val()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
state = {
  markers: []
};
constructor(props){
  super(props);
}

<FlatList
  data={this.state.markers}
  extraData={this.state.markers}
  renderItem={
    ({ item }) =>
      <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#000' }}>{item.useremail}</Text>
      </View>
  }
  style={{ width: '100%' }}
/>
```

Comment: Basically the problem is I can display my data in logs but can't display it in my Flatlist

Comment: Could you try and change `refx.once` callback to an arrow function? `refx.once("value", snapshot => {`. You should also ideally be calling your logic in `componentDidMount` as appose to will.